# Dynamically change title of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, button

I am trying to send some values when a button is clicked. Look at the example below, when I click the dog button the label should show dog etc.

I know I could add the text string to the button sender such as:

```
- (IBAction)ShowDog:(id)sender {

    SelectNum = 1;
    [label setStringValue:@"dog"];
}
```

however, this is not what I need.

I need to send values dynamically.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    if (SelectNum == 1) {
        [label setStringValue:@"dog"];
    }

    if (SelectNum == 2) {
        [label setStringValue:@"cat"];
    }

    if (SelectNum == 3) {
        [label setStringValue:@"human"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%i", SelectNum);

}

- (IBAction)ShowDog:(id)sender {

    SelectNum = 1;
}

- (IBAction)ShowCat:(id)sender{

    SelectNum = 2;

}

- (IBAction)ShowHuman:(id)sender{

    SelectNum = 3;

}
```

I have tried using NSDefault but the value is not changed instantly, also tried to set a timer but its not what i need for this app.

I just need to every tome I click a button the apps update the value in applicationDidFinishLaunching where all my code will be

Comment: Why is all of your code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? There should virtually no code in that method.

Comment: ok thats what I was starting to think.. where it should be? even if I add everything to a -(void) it want change

Comment: Got that I have to put all my code in awakeFromNib … but it still not working

Comment: You have a serious problem with understanding how iOS application programming in general.  I suggest that you start with some tutorial samples such as this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to change the title of UIButton on click then,

In viewDidLoad method of UIViewController: set action to btnDog:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [btnDog addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTitleToDog:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)changeTitleToDog:(id)sender {
   [btnDog setTitle:@"DOG" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```